# как запретить пользователю вводить числа в определенные ячейки datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть datagrid, в котором пользователь может редактировать информацию datagrid содержит несколько столбцов допустим : год, имя, название нужно запретить пользователю вводить числа в столбцы: имя и название, а в год - символы.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Тут нужна валидация. Валидировать можно как на уровне модели, так и на уровне контрола или свойств к нему привязанных. Как видно варианты есть разные, можно и совместить. Можно определиться с подходящим вариантом и конкретизировать вопрос